# Listing Users in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Morning All,

I seem to be having trouble with this and just wonder what I'm doing wrong, I haven't slept for 24 hours so a little tired...

I have a `pages_controller.rb` which I want to display certain column of users so I have placed the following code in my pages controller:

```
def index
 @users = User.all
end
```

However when I do the loop shown below:

```
 <%= @users.each do |u| %>
                  <%= u.company_name %>
                  <% end %>
```

I get the entire hash in my view:

```
Employer1 [#<User id: 1, email: "email@email.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$Nk9zpI4NdXrsuDxXcSyxAeyr2gWVfIfHEIxcMZzUU19e...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: "2013-12-18 19:59:12", sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2013-12-18 19:59:12", last_sign_in_at: "2013-12-17 19:14:12", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-12-17 19:13:57", updated_at: "2013-12-18 19:59:12", role_type: "employer", company_name: "Employer1", employer_desc: "Testing Description", area_of_focus: "Rails", number_of_employees: 50, first_name
```

Why is the happening and what am I doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your loop in your view as follows:

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <%= u.company_name %>
<% end %>
```

That is, replace `<%= @users.each do |u| %>` with `<% @users.each do |u| %>`.  Note erb scriptlets `<%=` vs. `<%` in each.  With `<%=` you are outputting anything that's within `<%= ... %>`

Comment: Wow I think I should really go to sleep, been going back to that for last 3 hours and haven't slept for 24, wait 25 hours now. Hmmm work in 2 hours...

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson, hmm sounds like it!  Glad to be of little help :)